# Error 500 after magento migration

Tags: magento2, error, migration, apache

The magento was installed in a testing environment.

1 - I copied all files from the folder and uploaded it to the production server folder.

2 - I exported the database and imported it into the production base.

3 - I put the appropriate permissions:

> "sudo find var vendor pub / static pub / media app / etc -type f
>   -exec chmod u + w {} \;
>
> sudo find var vendor pub / static pub / media app / etc -type d -exec
>   chmod u + w {} \;
>
> sudo chown -R www: www-data / var / www / html / magento sudo chmod u
>   + x bin / magento "

4 - Modwrite settings in production apache:

> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<Directory / var / www />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow, deny
    allow from all
</ Directory>
```

> sudo service apache2 restart

a2enmod rewrite "

5 - In the apache conf file I made the change:

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted

6 - I changed the memory of php to = `php_value memory_limit 256M`

7 - I cleaned the cache files of the `var/cache/* folder`

8 - The .htaccess file is missing from the `/var/www/html/` magento folder

Ask for help from you, everything I thought I could resolve I did.
But the problem persists, help me.

Comment: Hi! If you got an error 500 you should be able to find some clue/error message into the apache error log. Can you start looking there?

Comment: Please put `.htaccess` file in Magento2 root. It will work.

Comment: Working or not? **@Vanderson de Castro**

Answer (score 1):

Put `.htaccess` file in Magento2 root.

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Apache/PHP logs**

Check server logs for anything that might cause the error.

**Check Magento logs**

They are located in `var/log` folder of your Magento root. If you can't find any please check if they are enabled in `System > Configuration > Developer > Log settings.`

Run command:

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy